# duplicate items in Document after saving in a bean

Tags: xpages, javabeans, lotus-notes

I experience strange but reproduceable behaviour with an XPage which saves its values through a java bean. After copyAllItems to an document there are two richtext items in the document. First is empty, second is filled as expected.

This is my Xpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="docDataSource" formName="test"></xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:div id="test">
    <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{docDataSource.test}"></xp:fileUpload>
</xp:div>
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="test">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:registration.testCopyAllItems(docDataSource);}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

This is my java bean method:

```
public void testCopyAllItems(DominoDocument docDataSource) throws NotesException{
    Document docUser = database.createDocument(); // <- get any database
    docDataSource.getDocument(true).copyAllItems(docUser, true);
    docUser.save();
}
```

This is the result in the document:

[image]

Does anyone have a hint on what could cause the trouble?

Comment: This seems to be a "normal" behaviour and I have seen it a lot working with RichtText fields. It shouldn't matter. Notes can deal with a RichText field constisting of more then one item.

Comment: But when I want to programatically access the document to get the RichText Item I get an empty field.

Comment: Then delete the RichText field after `copyAllItems()` with `removeItem()` and copy it with `copyItem()` separately in the hope that it results in one item only.

Comment: That works for me. Write it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, thanks, I put this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a "normal" behaviour and I have seen it a lot working with RichtText fields. It shouldn't matter. Notes can deal with a RichText field constisting of more than one item.

As a workaround,

- delete the RichText field after `copyAllItems()` with `removeItem()` and
- copy it with `copyItem()` separately.

This should result in one item only.